# Cómo definir tiempos de duración e inicio de una animación?

Tags: javascript, html, css

hola quisiera ponerle un tiempo de inicio a la animación tiene un tiempo de duración. pero no de inicio.

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/?image=20);
}

@keyframes sube {
  0% {
    height: 0
  }
  100% {
    height: 240px
  }
}

#contenedor01 {
  position: fixed;
  left: calc(50% - 120px);
  bottom: calc(50% - 120px);
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: sube 5s linear forwards;
}

.imagen_animada {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id=contenedor01>
  <img class=imagen_animada src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Shamrock_svg.svg/240px-Shamrock_svg.svg.png>
</div>
```

como tengo varias imágenes todas inician al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Podrías utilizar un gif y pausarlo en el ultimo frame, o podrías hacer la animación css y utilizar animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-fill-mode: forwards;

Comment: prueba algo así: `<style>body {background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/?image=20);} @keyframes sube { 0% {bottom: -240px;} 100% { bottom: 100%; } };</style><img src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Shamrock_svg.svg/240px-Shamrock_svg.svg.png style="position: fixed; left : calc( 50% - 120px ); animation: sube 10s linear infinite;
">`

Comment: @aloMalbarez gracias. pero mira que la imagen ya esta completa y va subiendo. necesito es que la imagen este siempre en su punto base. y vaya creciendo hasta quedar completan. es como si uno estuviera sacando una carta de un sobre.

Comment: algo asi? `<style>body {background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/?image=20);} @keyframes sube { 0%{height:0} 100% {height:240px} };</style><div style="position:fixed;left:calc(50% - 120px);bottom:calc(50% - 120px);animation: sube 5s linear forward;width:240px;height:240px;overflow:hidden"><img style="position:absolute;bottom:0;" src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Shamrock_svg.svg/240px-Shamrock_svg.svg.png ></div>`

Comment: @aloMalbarez. esta vez copio pero no me sale animación. solo el fondo y el trebol pero estaticos amigo. no se si depronto lo copiaste mal o algo así. porque  a mi no me sale.

Comment: ah si es `forwards` para que quede donde termine la animación ( me comí una s )

Comment: @aloMalbarez hey amigo muchas gracias. me esta funcionando. ahora otro peque favor como hago para q la animacion empiece en x tiempo ya que como esta todas las imagenes me salen al mismo tiempo. y la idea es que el vaya pasando el tallo y cuando llege a una hoja esta se vaya mostrando. amigo muchas gracias!

Comment: @aloMalbarez la pregunta ha sido reabierta, pon tus comentarios como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Variando las posiciones de cada contenedor ( en este caso también uso un transform rotate [definiendo el origen de la rotación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) para reutilizar la imagen ) y especificando un [delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) (retraso) en segundos luego del [tipo de curva de aceleración](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) ( linear, entra rápido, sale rápido, etc.. ) es posible crear un set de animaciones coordinadas.

Hay que tener en cuenta que si los tiempos son largos y las imágenes muy grandes puede que se vea un temblequeo al renderizar las imágenes. Si reemplazas los png por svg por lo general va todo mas fluido.

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1200/?image=20);
}

@keyframes crece {
  0% {
    height: 0
  }
  100% {
    height: 240px
  }
}

.trebol {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 240px;
  height: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

#contenedor01 {
  left: calc(50% - 120px);
  bottom: calc(50% - 120px);
  animation: crece 5s linear forwards;
  z-index: 1;
}

#contenedor02 {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  animation: crece 2s linear 3s forwards;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  z-index: 0;
}

#contenedor03 {
  left: calc( 50% - 215px);
  bottom: calc( 50% - -45px);
  animation: crece 2s linear 3s forwards;
  transform: rotate(-63deg);
  z-index: 0;
}

.imagen_animada {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id=contenedor01 class=trebol>
  <img class=imagen_animada src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Shamrock_svg.svg/240px-Shamrock_svg.svg.png>
</div>

<div id=contenedor02 class=trebol>
  <img class=imagen_animada src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Shamrock_svg.svg/240px-Shamrock_svg.svg.png>
</div>

<div id=contenedor03 class=trebol>
  <img class=imagen_animada src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/15/Shamrock_svg.svg/240px-Shamrock_svg.svg.png>
</div>
```